# How to simplify this complex integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, numerical-methods

How to approximate this integral as a function of a and b?

$$\int_0^\pi\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{(a-b\sin\varphi\cos\theta)^2+(b\cos\varphi)^2+(b\sin\varphi\sin\theta)^2}d\theta d\varphi$$

where a and b are two variables.

Comment: Sorry for that. I have updated the question now

Comment: OK so the integral on $\theta$ is from 0 to $\pi$ correct? Or, wait. I think maybe it's the other way around?

Comment: integral on theta is from 0 to 2pi

Comment: Try expanding the argument of the square root.
I can see the statement $\cos^2 \theta + \sin^2 \theta = 1$ coming in handy. $$ \int_{0}^{2\pi} \sqrt{(a-b\sin\varphi\cos\theta)^2+(b\cos\varphi)^2+(b\sin\varphi\sin\theta)^2} \text{ d}\theta = \int_{0}^{2\pi} \sqrt{ a^2 + b^2 - 2ab\sin\varphi\cos\theta } \text{ d}\theta $$

Comment: Also: do you know if $a>b$ or vice versa. That would help.

Comment: If that is the case: may be both should be considered separately. i.e. a>b and b>a, because I need the solution for any set of values a and b.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was mentioned: the integrand simplifies to: $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2 - 2 a b \cos\theta \sin\phi}$

Factor out $\sqrt{a^2 +b^2}$ and use the binomial theorem to expand, treating $\cos\theta \sin \phi$ as small. This gives:

$$\sqrt{a^2 +b^2} \left(1-\frac{a b \cos (\theta ) \sin (\phi )}{a^2+b^2}-\frac{a^2 b^2 \cos ^2(\theta ) \sin ^2(\phi )}{2 \left(a^2+b^2\right)^2}-\frac{a^3 b^3 \cos ^3(\theta ) \sin ^3(\phi )}{2 \left(a^2+b^2\right)^3}-\cdots\right)$$

Now these functions can be integrated directly. (The odd powers of $\cos$ integrate to $0$ over the range here.)

For any $a,b$ you get some power series in $\left(\frac{a b}{a^2+b^2}\right)$

vis: $$\frac{\pi ^2 \sqrt{a^2+b^2}\left(2097152-\frac{262144 a^2 b^2}{\left(a^2+b^2\right)^2}-\frac{184320 a^4 b^4}{\left(a^2+b^2\right)^4}-\frac{268800 a^6 b^6}{\left(a^2+b^2\right)^6}-\frac{525525 a^8 b^8}{\left(a^2+b^2\right)^8}\right)}{1048576}$$